# How to change background color of WPF TextBlock ListBoxItem when mouse is over it?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The xaml below won't work because for ListBoxItem the BacckGround means the color under the TextBlock.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">                     
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Background.Hover}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
            Background="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Background}"
            Foreground="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Foreground}"
            Padding="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Padding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

For request I add my actual code here (SelectButton can be found here https://gist.github.com/loraderon/580405):

```
    <cntrls:SelectButton x:Name="Insert_BtnStartPolyline" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InsertLineItemsSource}" Command="{ui:CommandHandler OpenVersion}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="100">
        <cntrls:SelectButton.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </cntrls:SelectButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <cntrls:SelectButton.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </cntrls:SelectButton.Resources>
        <cntrls:SelectButton.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                            Background="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Background}"
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Foreground}"
                            Padding="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </cntrls:SelectButton.ItemTemplate>

    </cntrls:SelectButton>
```

Comment: Why not give the TextBlock a transparent background, and set the default background in the listboxitem style? Or put the mouse-over trigger in a style on the TextBlock?

Comment: @H.B. : I updated the question

Comment: @EdPlunkett : "or put mouse-over trigger in a style on the TextBlock" -> this exactly what i've been trying to do with many ways, but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Can you add a second block of XAML to your question, illustrating that version of your code? I sense a disturbance in the dependency properties.

Comment: my problem is that this is about https://gist.github.com/loraderon/580405 and not plain ListBox.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I added the actual XAML

Comment: @matti My spidey sense is keen today. Try removing `Background="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Background}"` from the TextBlock and putting it in a setter in the TextBlock style, inside the style but outside the Style.Triggers collection. When you set a property value via an attribute like that, it totally overrides anything the Style does. You're overriding the trigger with that Background attribute.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: thanks, but that did not work. both the trigger and setter have no effect in style in cntrls:SelectButton.Resources

Comment: Did you REMOVE the `Background` attribute from the TextBlock? Can you paste in that version of the XAML? If you did remove the background attribute, can you try setting the style explicitly on the TextBlock? `<TextBlock ...><TextBlock.Style><Style TargetType="TextBlock">...</Style></TextBlock.Style></TextBlock>`?

Comment: I removed it, but i put the style in cntrls:SelectButton.Resources. that style has no effect. i try your version where i suppose it's in DataTemplate

Comment: @EdPlunkett: It works!! Thanks a lot! You really helped me. Please write short answer if you will and I accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the right answer is this. I don't understand why defining the TextBlock style in cntrls:SelectButton.Resources failed to work, but we don't need that anyway.

The key thing here is *not* setting the default `Background` in an attribute on `TextBlock`, but rather in a `Setter` in the `Style`. That's because, by design, the attribute thing overrides whatever the style does. This is actually a good thing (once you know about it!) because it lets you explicitly override styling on a specific instance of a control.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding}" 
        Foreground="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Foreground}"
        Padding="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Padding}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.Button.Background}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks! Final question related to SelectButton is still to come :)